# How price is getting calculated for calling list api in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How price is getting calculated for list api in aws

Example 1 : Vms - DescribeInstance

Example 2 : Ebs - DescribeVolume

For example 1 and example 2

If i am hitting 1000 times so how price is getting calculated or no price will apply for list api.

Comment: Those api calls are free

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment some of the list api call is free in AWS but there are some limit is available.

If I take the example of AWS service catalog resource . kindly find the price for that

```
Number of API calls Price per call
1-1,000                         Free
Over 1,000                $0.0007 (14 calls for 1 cent)
```

Reference : https://aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/pricing/